# Rigid tensioner/turnbuckle: One side tightens, but the other side loosens

Tags: mechanical-engineering, threads

I'm attempting to make the rigid equivelent of a gate tensioner/turnbuckle. I'm doing this for a couple of reasons:

1. I like the idea of not fussing with cables
2. I'm using this experience to learn about the technology behind the turnbuckle

I've mocked up something that *almost* works. I've connected two hook-bolts to a threaded rod (5/16-18-36") via connectors.

It seemed like it would work in my head; I thought I would just be able to tighten one of the connectors to tension the gate. However, in practice, all I accomplish when tightening a connector is tightening one side, but then loosening the other side. The devise comes apart and fails miserably.

**What kind of mechanism would it take to make this work as expected?** In summary, I want to shorten the length of the device/rod by tightening a connector.

---

[image]

[image]

---

For bonus points: What is the principle called in Mechanical Engineering theory that would explain the problem where one side tightens, but the other side loosens?

Comment: Why are you using two turnbuckles, why not just use one - possibly located more centrally? Also, when you you the term " other side" do you mean other end?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To make this work, one side will need the "normal" righthand thread and the other a lefthand thread or  a rotating connection , but threads on both ends of the nut will not change the tension.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a turnbuckle that had thread that fit standard threaded rod.

*Note: Turnbuckles seem to often have non-standard thread. Maybe the thread is tighter for the heavy loads they sustain (relative to the length of thread)?*

I used a turnbuckle and replaced one of the hooks with a threaded rod (bent in a hook shape). All parts have 3/8" thread.

It seems to do the job well enough.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: For readers from Canada: I found the turnbuckle with standard thread at Home Hardware.

Comment: You forgot to point out why this works. As explained by @SolarMike the top hook has a reverse thread on it. It's visible in the photo.